# Confusion Over Applicative (->)

Tags: haskell

Given that `Applicative (->)` is implemented as:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

I am confused how the following works:

```
pure (+) <*> Just 3
```

My understanding is that:

```
f = pure (+)
g = Just 3
```

Based on that understanding, `<*>` would become:

```
-- f x (g x)
(pure (+)) x ((Just 3) x)
```

But this does not work since `(Just 3)` takes no parameters. So I apparently must be unaware of something, though I am not sure what that is.

I am baffled as to how this happens:

```
Prelude> :t pure (+) <*> Just 3
pure (+) <*> Just 3 :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
```

Please explain how this works. Doing the steps manually, based on my understanding of things, I am not able to reach the same outcome as `ghci`.

Comment: This example illustrates the Maybe instance of Applicative, not the `(->) a` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the right-hand-side argument to `<*>` is `Just 3`, then the Applicative instance being used must be that of Maybe, not of functions. So, the left-hand side must be a Maybe as well, thus `pure (+) == Just (+)`. Now you can see how `<*>` combines these: it unwraps the two `Just` constructors, applies the function, and puts the result back into a `Just`: this is the same as `Just ((+) 3)`, or `Just (3 +)`. And as you can see in ghci, those two things have the same type.

Comment: Fantastic! That is the piece that I was missing, that Applicative Maybe was actually the one being applied. For future reference, how could I have known that it is the right-hand side that determines the class instance? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Both sides determine it: they must be the same. I was describing the process the type inferencer (GHCI's, and the one in your head) goes through to discover which instance is being used. The type of `<*>` is `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and all three `f`s are necessarily the same. Since the right-hand side is clearly "locked" at `f ~ Maybe`, you can infer that the left-hand side (and return type) must also have `f ~ Maybe`, and that's how you discover which `pure` and `<*>` are in play.

Comment: @kurzweil4 Don't forget that if `x::a` then `pure x` will be of type `f a` for any applicative `f`. In your case, `a` already involves an applicative (`(->) b`), but that is irrelevant. By comparison, `(+) <*> ...` forces `<*>` to work on the `(->) b` applicative, since that's what's on the left; however, `pure (+) <*> ...` does not force any particular one, and will adapt to whichever applicative is on the right side.